# How to update value of a key in dictionary in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dictionary, key-value

I have the following code in c# , basically it's a simple dictionary with some keys and their values.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary =
    new Dictionary<string, int>();
dictionary.Add("cat", 2);
dictionary.Add("dog", 1);
dictionary.Add("llama", 0);
dictionary.Add("iguana", -1);
```

I want to update the key 'cat' with new value **5**.
How could I do this?

Comment: Really? Did you try google/bing/prefered-search-engine first?

Comment: I did and this was the first result! way to be constructive!

Answer (score 41):

Have you tried just

```
dictionary["cat"] = 5;
```

:)

**Update**

```
dictionary["cat"] = 5+2;
dictionary["cat"] = dictionary["cat"]+2;
dictionary["cat"] += 2;
```

*Beware of non-existing keys* :)

Comment: but what if i want to add new value into existing value ?

Comment: @AhsanAshfaq, what exactly do you mean by "add to existing one"?

Comment: well @JHON it also works . Thanks budy you really help me thankyou very much

Comment: Just check if a key exist and update its value, if not then add a new dictionary entry.

Comment: thanks @cubski for your suggestion its a good one

Comment: @AhsanAshfaq: You can find a simple implementation below.

Answer (score 19):

Try this simple function to add an dictionary item if it does not exist or update when it exists:

```
    public void AddOrUpdateDictionaryEntry(string key, int value)
    {
        if (dict.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            dict[key] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            dict.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
```

This is the same as dict[key] = value.

Comment: That is same as `dict[key] = value` in one line. Also I would call the funcation `AddOrUpdate`

Comment: @nawfal They are not the same, the difference is it checks for the key first. If it exists, it adds the new value if not it creates a new entry. Good point on the function name though.

Comment: which is same as `dict[key] = value`.. What do you think `dict[key] = value` does?

Comment: @nawfal You are right. I have always thought dict[key] would throw an exception when the key doesn't exist. You learn something new everyday. Thanks.

Comment: dict[key] will throw KeyNotfoundException when the key doesn't exist.    You have to be setting it to create it.  dict[key] = value

Comment: @DanBut Actually, it doesn't. It will add the dictionary entry when the key doesn't exist and update the value of the entry if it does exist.

Comment: @DanBut I misunderstood your comment, you are right. When say doing dict[newKey] (without assigning a value), it would throw an exception. But when doing dict[newKey] = value, it wouldn't throw an exception instead will add new entry if the key value doesn't exist and update it if it does exist. Just want to clarify for others.

Comment: Yep I was not very clear.       
`var x = dict[key]` will throw when key does not exist.
`dict[key] = x` will not throw when key does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Just use the indexer and update directly:

```
dictionary["cat"] = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is a key value pair. Catch Key by

```
dic["cat"]
```

and assign its value like

```
dic["cat"] = 5
```